How to retime your Animation/Keys in Timeline?
I've been struggling with this one for quite some time now, is there a way to select some keys in Timeline and scale them?

How long have you been struggling...? Do you know Blender's shortcut for scaling, S? Have you thought about trying that? The question is: do you want to scale their distribution over the frame range, for example before scaling they are from 0 to 30 and you want them from 0 to 60? Or do you want to also (or only) scale the values they hold, i.e. when on frame 30 the X value is 5, you want to scale it to 10? Or to frame 60 and X = 10?

If you just want to scale your keyframes over the range of the Timeline (which is what retiming sounds to me like), then you can simply select all the keyframes you want to scale and hit S to scale them.
Scaling in the Timeline uses the 2D Cursor (the vertical blue line showing you which frame you are currently on) as pivot point, so you can for example scale from the starting frame everything further out, or from the first keyframe of the animation if it's not on frame 1 if you want to keep the beginning of the animation on a certain frame, you can scale from somewhere inbetween outwards or perhaps scale from the last keyframe of the animation if you want to make sure it ends on a certain frame:

In the Graph Editor you have a few more options for scaling the keyframes. First of all you can use different pivot points: Bounding Box Center, 2D Cursor and Individual Centers. In the following example I will use the 2D Cursor like in the Timeline.
You can either scale generally in 2 dimensions X and Y evenly by hitting S, this will change the positions of keyframes and their values.
Or just like scaling objects in the viewport you can limit it to either X or Y axis by pressing the letter afterwards, so S X to scale horizontally, which will only change the keyframe positions, or S Y to scale vertically, which will only change the keyframes' values, but not their positions.


Wow, Thanks Gordon you solved one of my blender mysteries which was really easy so sorry about that, but I've been searching for this piece of info on youtube and I even googled it so I think the word "retime" wasn't the best keyword to use.
Besides I tried using the scale tool by clicking on the scale tool from toolbox which didn't work so I think hitting S was the answer.
Thanks again Gordon and sorry for the bother :)

@AhmadMohsen I've added some more scaling at the end of the answer. The toolbox is in the viewport window, and as almost all tools and shortcuts in Blender they are "editor-window-sensitive", you can only use them where they are available or in case of shortcuts, they work in the editor window you are currently in with your mouse and nowhere else.

An cool tip also is to use ⇧ Shift + T and slide your keyframes. It can be useful on some situations.
